# IPFiltering Asp Net Core

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I'm using the following nuget package : https://github.com/msmolka/ZNetCS.AspNetCore.IPFiltering

I'm using it to block IP that are trying to bruteforce the authentication of my app.
The Blacklist is defined in the appsetting.json, and I don't know how to dynamicaly modify it during runtime, for example, add an IP that has a bad password.

The way I'm actually doing isn't working as I still can connect even if the IP is correctly persisted in the conf ...

Startup.cs

```
namespace Sondage
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddIPFiltering(this.Configuration.GetSection("IPFiltering"));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseIPFiltering();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

}

appsettings.json

```
{
    "Logging": {
       "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        } 
     },
     "AllowedHosts": "*",

     "IPFiltering": {
     "DefaultBlockLevel": "None",
     "HttpStatusCode": 404,
     "Blacklist": [],
     "IgnoredPaths": [ "GET:/ignoreget", "*:/ignore" ]
 }
```

}

Part of my controller :

```
[Route("api/authenticate")]
[ApiController]
public class authenticationController : ControllerBase
{

    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public authenticationController(IConfiguration Configuration)
    {
        _configuration = Configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string authent(string value)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        IPAddress ip_addr = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

        if(!Globals.tryByIP.TryGetValue(ip_addr, out int numberOfTry)) {
            Globals.tryByIP.Add(ip_addr, 0);
        } else
        {
            if(numberOfTry>=0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----");
                _configuration.GetSection("IPFiltering")["Blacklist"] = ip_addr.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(_configuration.GetSection("IPFiltering")["Blacklist"]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Usually config files are read only - that's why you don't have any methods to modify and save them in the api. If you still want to change it during runtime, you could read it as any other text file, modify, and save using libraries from System.IO and Newtonsoft. If you want your changes reflected in application, you should set `reloadOnChange` flag in `AddJsonFile` to true. Here is an example how to do that: https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/17/automatically-reload-typed-configuration-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the [IPAddressRange](https://github.com/jsakamoto/ipaddressrange) package as well.

I had problems recently with this nuget package as well, and at first I forgot to add the ipaddress parser.